# Import SQL file into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows, import

I have a database called `nitm`. I haven't created any tables there. But I have a SQL file which contains all the necessary data for the database. The file is `nitm.sql` which is in `C:\ drive`. This file has size of about 103 MB. I am using wamp server.

I have used the following syntax in MySQL console to import the file:

```
mysql>c:/nitm.sql;
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Finally, i solved the problem. I placed the `nitm.sql` file in `bin` file of the `mysql` folder and used the following syntax.

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin>mysql -u root nitm < nitm.sql
```

And this worked.

Comment: This is not from the mysql console as OP asked, but from a console into mysql. The answer from Robert Anthony Tribiana does describe how to do it from the mysql console.

Comment: This is not the exact way to solve the problem, it's  not a solution.

Comment: You guys know that this was the OP who answered this?

Comment: If your mysql need a password, then is method won't work, you need the top answer of @d-_-b

Answer (score 427):

From the mysql console:

mysql> `use DATABASE_NAME;`

mysql> `source path/to/file.sql;`

make sure there is no slash before path if you are referring to a relative path... it took me a while to realize that! lol

Comment: You don't need a slash before the path if you're making a relative reference. If you're going from the root you will, ie `/home/user/file.sql`

Comment: What a pity there's no way to add an answer to favourites :(

Comment: In Chrome they are called bookmarks, and you can just click the star in address bar ;)

Comment: you saved my life :) thanks! ... this was for me also solution for Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column - MySQL

Comment: @ArseniuszŁozicki add the question and you will be able to reach answer :) that is what i do.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's much easier to remember than the other ways to import

Comment: Just to add to this answer that the `path/to/file.sql` is the local file system path where the  mysql *client* is at. There are times where MySQL server expect the path to be on the server side, I.E. `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` which drops the file into the path on the MySQL server!

Comment: I found that the relative path is where you invoke the mysql command.

Comment: is there a way to disable the verbosity when doing it like that?

Comment: Also,don't forget to delete the .sql file after upload

Comment: I wonder if `source` command works on other mysql clients, like `libmysqlclient` and other embedded clients in various languages.

Answer (score 54):

If you are using wamp you can try this. Just type `use your_Database_name` first.

1. Click your wamp server icon then look for `MYSQL > MSQL Console` then run it.
2. If you dont have password, just hit enter and type :

   ```
   mysql> use database_name;
   mysql> source location_of_your_file;
   ```

   If you have password, you will promt to enter a password. Enter you password first then type:

   ```
   mysql> use database_name;
   mysql> source location_of_your_file;
   ```

`location_of_your_file` should look like `C:\mydb.sql`

so the commend is **mysql>source C:\mydb.sql;**

This kind of importing sql dump is very helpful for BIG SQL FILE.

I copied my file `mydb.sq` to directory `C:` .It should be capital C: in order to run

and that's it.

Comment: This answer seems WAMP specific while the shown code works from any environment running MySQL where you can access MySQL via a terminal or a console.

Answer (score 26):

In windows, if the above suggestion gives you an error (file not found or unknown db) you may want to double the forward slashes:

In the mysql console:

```
mysql> use DATABASE_NAME;

mysql> source C://path//to//file.sql;
```

Comment: Single forward slash worked for me in my Windows machine.

Answer (score 18):

Ok so, I'm using Linux but I think this holds true for Windows too.
You can do this either directly from the command prompt

```
> mysql -u <user name> -p<password> <database name> < sqlfilename.sql
```

Or from within the mysql prompt, you can use:

```
mysql>source sqlfilename.sql
```

But both these approaches have their own benefits in the results they display.
In the first approach, the script exits as soon as it encounters an error. And the better part, is that it tells you the exact line number in the source file where the error occurred. However, it ONLY displays errors. If it didn't encounter any errors, the scripts displays NOTHING. Which can be a little unnerving. Because you're most often running a script with a whole pile of commands.

Now second approach (from within the mysql prompt) has the benefit that it displays a message for every different MySQL command in the script. If it encounters errors, it displays the mysql error message but continues on through the scripts. This can be good, because you can then go back and fix all the errors before you run the script again. The downside is that it does NOT display the line numbers in the script where the errors were encountered. This can be a bit of a pain. But the error messages are as descriptive so you could probably figure out where the problem is.

I, for one, prefer the directly-from-OS-command line approach.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using xampp

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -uroot -p nitm < nitm.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

You are almost there
use

```
mysql> \. c:/nitm.sql;
```

You may also access help by

```
mysql> \?
```

Comment: This didn't work. When I used mysql> \. c:/nitm.sql; , it threw error like Failed to open file 'c:\nitm.sql;', error: 2

Comment: Have you tried variations of this? Some applications respect C:\nitm.sql

Comment: Also note the semicolon at the end is not required. So remove it. Another option is 'cd c:' then try "\. nitm.sql"

Comment: Please think before you type. 'cd c:' is the command for DOS prompt not mySql console.

Comment: `mysql> \. ~/Downloads/backups/file.sql`

worked perfectly within mysql>

and from terminal `coosal` answer worked also.

Answer (score 7):

For localhost on XAMPP. Open a cmd window and type

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root -p
```

**Attention! No semi-colon after -p**
Enter your password and type

```
use database_name;
```

to select the database you need.

Check if your table is there

```
show tables;
```

Import from your sql file

```
source sqlfile.sql;
```

I have put my file on C:\xampp\mysql\bin location in order to don't mix up with locations of sql file.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Check [MySQL Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html).

Note: It is better to use the full path of the SQL file `file.sql`.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux I navigated to the directory containing the .sql file before starting mysql.   The system cursor is now in the same location as the file and you won't need a path.  Use source myData.sql  where my date is replaced with the name of your file.

```
cd whatever directory

mysql - p
```

---

connect targetDB

```
source myData.sql
```

Done

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to use

```
charset utf8
```

If your sql file is in utf-8 :)

So you need to do:

> cmd.exe
>
> mysql -u root
>
> mysql> charset utf8
>
> mysql> use mydbname
>
> mysql> source C:\myfolder\myfile.sql

Good luck ))

Answer (score 2):

from the command line (cmd.exe, not from within mysql shell) try something like:

```
type c:/nite.sql | mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname
```

Comment: I haven't created any password for database so it's blank in password field. And I have used the above syntax like this c:/nitm.sql | mysql -u root -p  nitm but this also didn't work. Can you help me with this some more?

Comment: Omitting -p didn't work as well. This threw error like 'c:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Does your dump contain features that are not supported in your version of MySQL? You can also try to remove the starting (and ending) MySQL commented SET-statements.

I don't know if your dump comes from a Linux version of MySQL (line endings)?

Comment: I have already deleted the mysql commented SET-statements. But still the error occurs.

Comment: You can try to login to the MySQL command shell and the use then statement: "source c:\nite.sql". Don't forget to select the correct database.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed my wamp server in D: drive so u have to go to the following path from ur command line->(and if u have installed ur wamp in c: drive then just replace the d: wtih c: here)

```
D:\>cd wamp
D:\wamp>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin>cd mysql
D:\wamp\bin\mysql>cd mysql5.5.8 (whatever ur verserion will be displayed here use keyboard Tab button)
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin>mysql -u root -p password db_name < "d:\backupfile.sql"
```

here **root** is user of my phpmyadmin
**password** is the password for phpmyadmin so **if u haven't set any password for root just nothing type at that place,**
db_name is the database (for which database u r taking the backup)
,backupfile.sql is the file from which u want ur backup of ur database and u can also change the backup file location(d:\backupfile.sql) from to any other place on your computer

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql>c:/nitm.sql;
```

That would write the output of the mysql command to 'nitm.sql;' (What's the ';' supposed to do?) Assuming you've got a copy of the original file (before you overwrote it) then:

```
mysql < c:/nitm.sql
```

Comment: This didn't work either. It threw error like ERROR 1064 <42000>: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql < c:/nitm.sql' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Export Particular DataBases

```
 djimi:> mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 --password=test -B CCR KIT >ccr_kit_local.sql
```

this will export CCR and KIT databases...

Import All Exported DB to Particular Mysql Instance  (You have to be where your dump file is)

```
djimi:> mysql --user=root --host=localhost --port=3306 --password=test < ccr_kit_local.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows OS the following commands works for me.

```
mysql>Use <DatabaseName>
mysql>SOURCE C:/data/ScriptFile.sql;
```

No single quotes or double quotes around file name. Path would contain '/' instead of '\'.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you struggling with getting this done trying every possible answer you can find on SO. Here's what worked for me on a VPS running Windows 2012 R2 :

1. Place your sql file wherever the bin is for me it is located at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`
2. Open windows command prompt (cmd)
3. Run `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin > mysql -u [username] -p`
4. Enter your password
5. Run command `use [database_name]`;
6. Import your file with command source `C://Program Files//MySQL//MySQL Server 8.0//bin//mydatabasename.sql`

It did it for me as everything else had failed. It might help you too.