# Importing Mysql database using Ruby/Chef Recipe for Vagrant

Tags: mysql, ruby, chef-infra, recipe, vagrant

I am writing a chef script to automate setting dev environments. I can get a database created and grant privileges but I am trying to find out a way to import a mysql dump file into the database that has just been created.

My code for granting the access is

```
ruby_block "Execute grants" do
  block do

    require 'rubygems'
    Gem.clear_paths
    require 'mysql'

    m = Mysql.new('localhost', "root", node[:mysql][:server_root_password])
    m.query("GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '#{node[:mysql][:server_root_password]}'")
    m.query('FLUSH PRIVILEGES')
end
end
```

and I was hoping I would be able to do the following query
    `#m.query("-u root -p root db_name < /project/db/import.sql")`

but is just gives me an error.

I haven't done much Ruby so finding it hard to figure out. Anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a file path error, and you're using chef solo, try using the path specified within *solo.rb*, like:

```
/tmp/chef-solo/site-cookbooks/path_to_file.sql
```

As a general note, consider using the [database cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database) for mysql user and database management tasks. Once you setup the necessary cookbook dependencies, you can put code like this into your main recipe's *default.rb*:

```
# externalize conection info in a ruby hash
mysql_connection_info = {
  :host => "localhost",
  :username => 'root',
  :password => node['mysql']['server_root_password']
}

# drop if exists, then create a mysql database named DB_NAME
mysql_database 'DB_NAME' do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  action [:drop, :create]
end

# query a database from a sql script on disk
mysql_database "DB_NAME" do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  sql { ::File.open("/tmp/chef-solo/site-cookbooks/main/path/to/sql_script.sql").read }
  action :query
end

#or import from a dump file
mysql_database "DB_NAME" do
  connection mysql_connection_info
  sql "source /tmp/chef-solo/site-cookbooks/main/path/to/sql_dump.sql;"
end
```

Haven't tested that last one because storing a database file within the chef directory really slows things down.

See also: [Import SQL file into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-from-mysql-console)

Comment: The `source` command is only implemented in the `mysql` CLI tool — not MySQL itself, so attempting to use it from Ruby results in a syntax error.  The `File.open().read` solution works well for small .sql files, however [it throws an error if the file is larger than 1MB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25477128/27581).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a backup from the MySQL command line client, but not from within a SQL query.  You need to execute the command from the shell.  I believe the `execute` resource might do the trick for you:

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Execute

Comment: I think I now have the correct code in place but I think the problem is that in the command line the following works `mysql -p -u root test_project < import.sql` but you get a password prompt which needs filling in, then it executes the command. I am using the execute resource with the same command but even if I specify the password using -p it fails.

Comment: you can include the password on the command line. `mysql -u root -pSecret test_project < import.sql` will not prompt for a password (assuming you get your password right. You will have to include the password in the chef script, but for a dev vagrant vm config this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: An alternative is to use randomly generated passwords, as wordpress does for its chef recipe: https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/wordpress

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a Ruby guy, but I managed to get Chef to import a large `.sql` file by leveraging the `mysql` command line tool.  Challenges I needed to solve:

- Import a `.sql` file in the 100's of MB range (YMMV if you need GBs or TBs)
- **Idempotentcy** — only run the import if the `.sql` file has changed
- Not pass credentials to MySQL as command parameters (a security concern)

First I created a `.my.cnf` file template to pass the credentials:

#### templates/default/.my.cnf.erb

```
[client]
host=<%= @host %>
user=<%= @user %>
password="<%= @password %>"
```

Then I added a resource to my recipe that would populate the template:

#### recipes/import-db.rb

```
template '/root/.my.cnf' do
  mode 0600
  variables({
    :host => 'localhost',
    :user => 'root',
    :password => node[:your_cookbook][:db][:root_password],
  })
end
```

(Where `node[:your_cookbook][:db][:root_password]` is an attribute that contains the MySQL root password)

**Security Note**: for simplicity I'm doing the import as the `root` user.  If the `.sql` file to be imported is not from a trusted source, you will want to run `mysql` as a limited user and connect to MySQL with a limited db user that only has access to the database in question.

Finally, I added another resource to the recipe that actually executes the import:

```
backup_sql = '/path/to/the/db-backup.sql'
db_last_modified = "/etc/db-#{node[:your_cookbook][:db][:name]}.lastmodified"

execute 'restore backup' do
  command "mysql #{node[:your_cookbook][:db][:name]} <'#{backup_sql}' && touch '#{db_last_modified}'"
  not_if { FileUtils.uptodate?(db_last_modified, [backup_sql]) }
end
```

(Where `node[:your_cookbook][:db][:name]` is the name of the MySQL database that will be restored.)