# mysql chef database recipe fails on large file

Tags: mysql, vagrant, chef-infra

"MySQL server has gone away". Hmm.

I am using vagrant and chef to setup my virtual development environment. I'm almost there, but on the last step chef fails when attempting to execute my external db_setup.sql file. I can execute this same script by SSH'ing into the virtual server and it installs without difficulty.

This is my problem code (in cookbooks/database/recipies/mysql.rb file):

```
# Query a database from a sql script on disk
mysql_database 'run script' do
  database_name 'my_db'
  connection mysql_connection_info
  retries 3
  sql { ::File.open('/vagrant/db_setup.sql').read }
  action :query
end
```

The file is 6.9mb and the error I receive when I run `vagrant provision` is:

```
==> default: [2014-08-24T16:04:53-07:00] ERROR: mysql_database[run script] 
(database::mysql line 50) had an error: Mysql::Error: MySQL server has gone away
```

For what it's worth, **when I replace** the db_setup.sql file with a smaller, simpler file that just creates a few empty tables, it executes without difficulty.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Many, many things can [cause this error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html). In my experience it's usually an SQL file of over 1MB, or, the wait_timeout in your servers my.cnf is set very low (sixty seconds) needs properly tuned. When deploying my.cnf try a wait_timeout 86400 and a max_allowed_packet of "enough" to import that file.

For example:

```
 [mysqld]
 wait_timeout = 86400
 max_allowed_packet = 1GB
```

PS. I would not recommend this high of parameters in actual production.

Comment: This would make sense, but if that were the issue, would I be able to (I can) ssh into the box and process the script from the command line?

Comment: For what it's worth, I did make these changes to my.cnf and restarted server and the provisioning process still failed. To confirm, I also ssh'ed into the server and ran `source db_setup.sql` and everything ran successfully. Any thoughts? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue [by getting Chef to leverage the `mysql` command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528155/27581) instead of using Ruby to read the `.sql` file.