# Transfer files from local computer to remote server

Tags: mysql, command-line, putty

I need to transfer a csv file from my local computer runninng windows 7 to a remote server which runs linux, through putty, in order to create a database on the remote server. I've searched for possible ways of doing and have found the following.

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(colname1, colname2, colname3)
```

This one would allow me to import the csv file from my local machine, or I'm guessing the remote server after I get the file there, however it  doesn't help me get the file to the server.

I also found the found the following command-line which I can use from here: [Import a local SQL File To MySQL on a Remote Server Using SSH Tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719662/import-a-local-sql-file-to-mysql-on-a-remote-server-using-ssh-tunnel)

```
c:>pscp source_file_name userid@server_name:/path/destination_file_name.
```

which I could possibly use, however I'm unclear on a couple things.

First of all the remote server I'm accessing doesn't use a name, it uses an IP address and a specific port. Secondly, I'm unsure of how the command handles the file transfer and where it ends up. When I log onto the server it starts off in my own directory.

If you have experience using this command, where exactly will the file get transfered to? Is the desintation path from the root directory or would it be from my home directory?

Also if you have any other alternative methods of transfering the files let me know.

Comment: If you can SCP the file to the database server it's a lot easier. Most SCP clients allow specifying arbitrary names and ports with command-line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I assume based on the fact that you use putty, you actually access the server through ssh. If so, then I'd go with the WinSCP SFTP combo.