# How to export and import a .sql file from command line with options?

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-line-arguments, sqlcommand

**Not Duplicate!** looking for some feature have phpmyadmin during export in command line

I want to export and import a .sql file to and from a MySQL database from **command line**.

Is there any command to export .sql file in MySQL? Then how do I import it?

When doing the export/import, there may be **constraints** like enable/disable **foreign key check** or **export only table structure**.

Can we set those **options** with `mysqldump`?

*some example of Options*

[image]

Comment: `mysqldump` is a separate command. You shouldn't be in `mysql` when running it. Just write it in front of the command prompt.

And a semicolon is to tell the mysql prompt that the command has ended. Since you are running mysqldump as a program on the terminal, you should not end it with semi-colon.

Comment: thanks Ozair & all of guys also is there any way to set attributes like set foreign key,structure only,data only

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Comment: checked mysql options but not found any way for export structure/data only

Comment: @Samuel Liew Why this question marked duplicate, i asked this question before above questions, have you checked asked date ?

Answer (score 173):

Type the following command to import sql data file:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

In this example, import 'data.sql' file into 'blog' database using vivek as username:

```
$ mysql -u vivek -p -h localhost blog < data.sql
```

If you have a dedicated database server, replace localhost hostname with with actual server name or IP address as follows:

```
$ mysql -u username -p -h 202.54.1.10 databasename < data.sql
```

To export a database, use the following:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

Note the `<` and `>` symbols in each case.

Comment: When you are exporting using `mysqldump` how do you add the port?

Answer (score 42):

If you're already running the SQL shell, you can use the `source` command to import data:

```
use databasename;
source data.sql;
```

Comment: Best option to import dumped data.if you have exported data using mysqldump then this option to import will work in seconds.

Answer (score 31):

mysqldump will not dump database events, triggers and routines unless explicitly stated when dumping individual databases;

```
mysqldump -uuser -p db_name --events --triggers --routines > db_name.sql
```

Comment: Does this include Indicies?

Answer (score 30):

Well you can use below command to export,

> mysqldump --databases --user=root --password your_db_name >
>   export_into_db.sql

and the generated file will be available in the same directory where you had ran this command.

Now login to mysql using command,

> mysql -u[username] -p

then use "source" command with the file path.

Answer (score 21):

Dump an entire database to a file:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p password DATABASENAME > FILENAME.sql
```

Comment: And How can we set constraints like enable/disable foreign key check or export only table structure with mysqldump

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
mysqldump databaseExample > file.sql
```

Comment: Where does it dump it too? What location in the local drive?

Answer (score 8):

since I have no enough reputation to comment after the highest post, so I add here.

use '|' on linux platform to save disk space.

thx @Hariboo, add events/triggers/routints parameters

```
mysqldump -x -u [uname] -p[pass]  -C --databases db_name  --events --triggers --routines | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/ '  | awk '{ if (index($0,"GTID_PURGED")) { getline; while (length($0) > 0) { getline; } } else { print $0 } }'  | grep -iv 'set @@' | trickle -u 10240 mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME
```

some issues/tips:

Error: ......not exist when using LOCK TABLES

```
# --lock-all-tables，-x , this parameter is to keep data consistency because some transaction may still be working like schedule.
# also you need check and confirm: grant all privileges on *.* to root@"%" identified by "Passwd";
```

ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 866: MySQL server has gone away
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

```
# set this values big enough on destination mysql server, like: max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*20
# use compress parameter '-C'
# use trickle to limit network bandwidth while write data to destination server
```

ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 32730: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

```
# set SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
# or use super user import data
```

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 138: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

```
# add sed/awk to avoid some privilege issues
```

hope this help!

Comment: I ran into the ERROR 1227 (42000). Not sure what did you mean by add sed/awk.

Comment: What is "x" in your syntax? `mysqldump -x -u [uname] -p[pass]  -C`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this **script to export or import** any database from terminal given at this link: https://github.com/Ridhwanluthra/mysql_import_export_script/blob/master/mysql_import_export_script.sh

```
echo -e "Welcome to the import/export database utility\n"
echo -e "the default location of mysqldump file is: /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump\n"
echo -e "the default location of mysql file is: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql\n"
read -p 'Would like you like to change the default location [y/n]: ' location_change
read -p "Please enter your username: " u_name
read -p 'Would you like to import or export a database: [import/export]: ' action
echo

mysqldump_location=/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump
mysql_location=/opt/lampp/bin/mysql

if [ "$action" == "export" ]; then
    if [ "$location_change" == "y" ]; then
        read -p 'Give the location of mysqldump that you want to use: ' mysqldump_location
        echo
    else
        echo -e "Using default location of mysqldump\n"
    fi
    read -p 'Give the name of database in which you would like to export: ' db_name
    read -p 'Give the complete path of the .sql file in which you would like to export the database: ' sql_file
    $mysqldump_location -u $u_name -p $db_name > $sql_file
elif [ "$action" == "import" ]; then
    if [ "$location_change" == "y" ]; then
        read -p 'Give the location of mysql that you want to use: ' mysql_location
        echo
    else
        echo -e "Using default location of mysql\n"
    fi
    read -p 'Give the complete path of the .sql file you would like to import: ' sql_file
    read -p 'Give the name of database in which to import this file: ' db_name
    $mysql_location -u $u_name -p $db_name < $sql_file
else
    echo "please select a valid command"
fi
```