# When i export my table, Still not completed stops

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I have a big table on my local database *(phpmyadmin)*.
When I export my table, IDM *(internet download manager)* will start downloading and still not completed stops.

For example, my table size is `80Mb`, but my export file will be `50Mb`. In oder words, the number of my rows are `+300,000`, But when I download my table, those will be `+180,000`.

> **Note:** My export file is not always the same, But often, it is between 50mb and 60mb.

Why does phpmyadmin kills export? *(downloading)*. How can i fix it ?!

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error logs of your local server?

Comment: @ethan How should i do that ?

Comment: @ethan Really Is it related with PHP ?

Comment: I guess I'm working off the assumption you're using phpmyadmin to export your table.  Since phpmyadmin is php, it's a good place to start.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle phpMyAdmin - 2.11.9.2

Comment: Any chance you can update? this version is ancient, and improvements have been done for export since.

Comment: @MarcDelisle all right, I will change it, tnx

Comment: FWIW, I have the same issue in phpMyAdmin 4.4.15. I'm on goDaddy shared hosting with a wordpress site. It cuts off just short of 50mb with no errors

Comment: @IvanDurst [enjoy it ...!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line/21091197?noredirect=1#21091197)

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is you have a very meager max_execution_time, and php is killing the export before it can be completed.

Comment: where i can change max_execution_time ? php.ini ?

Comment: I changed `max_execution_time`=5500. but didn't worked. I think `max_execution_time` is for execute and i should change other thing ...

Answer (score 0):

Could be memory or execution time limit.

Change script execution time limit with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) (note the value is in seconds)
Also, increase the memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', 'xM');` where x is an integer value (i.e.: 128).

If you're handling a huge database and you have SSH access to your server it's better to use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)