# Can't get mysqldump to work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a copy of a database so I can send it as to someone else as a file so they can use the copy. I'm trying to use mysqldump for this, I'm looking at the documentation but I can't get it to work.

I'm just trying to copy a database called `test2` right now. In the MySQL command line client I'm doing `mysqldump test2 > dump.sql;` I'm getting the error message: `You have an error in your SQL suntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump test2 > dump.sql' at line 1.`

Go on, tell me I'm stupid. I just need some help, please.

Comment: Do you have a DB named `test2`?

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, that was a typo.

Comment: Check this out:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/downloading-mysql-dump-from-command-line][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/downloading-mysql-dump-from-command-line

Comment: Post the exact error statement.

Comment: Show the exact command you are trying to run in command prompt. There is something before the command

Comment: @Rahul I don't have more to post, that is the exact code I've tried.

Comment: @DhananjayaMahaMalage When running that from the windows CDM, do you have to run it from a specific directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to export and import a .sql file from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following from the Unix command line to back up and recreated databases:

1. Back up a database:

General:

```
$ mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> -h<hostname> <database> | gzip - > <database>.dump.<datestamp>.gz
```

Example:

```
$ mysqldump -usandro -psecrete -hlocalhost books | gzip - > books.dump.2015-06-20.gz
```

2. Load a database from backup

   $ gunzip -c books.dump.2015-06-20.gz | mysql -usandro2 -psecrete2 -host2

*gzip* and *gunzip* are used to compress and uncompress the backup file to save space.  The *-* and the *-c* are used for *stdin* and *stdout*.  Normally *gzip* and *gunzip* work on files.

The loading example will create the database should it not exist.  If the database already exists, the loading will replace all existing tables with new ones.

Comment: In the cmd, do you have to run the `$ mysqldum...` from a specific directory? I've tried running the windows version of that code in the cmd, just in my users account `C:\Users\Mitch`, and I get errors.

Comment: You do not need to run it from any spec. directory - but the mysqldump command needs to be in your path.   What errors are you getting?