# Is there a command to save my databse to a folder?

Tags: mysql

For my coursework I am creating a mysql database and I must submit my work by copying it to my submission folder. Using command line, how would I submit it to a folder like this: /folder/a001/submittedwork/my_work

Comment: just path to it (adding path prior to outFile name)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You can use : mysqldump

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

If you are using mysql I think you should take a look at mariaDB.

Comment: What purpose is behind mentioning `MariaDB` in this answer?

Comment: I think mariaDB has a better command line interface and is more powerfull. Nowadays it should be a better place to start to learn mysql.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on that? This is a statement that is a bit surprising in my eyes. So it should be accompanied with some real examples or evidence...

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Comment: mariaDB is a fork of mysql by some of main developer of mysql :
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/
https://seravo.fi/2015/10-reasons-to-migrate-to-mariadb-if-still-using-mysql

Comment: Good god. The "main developer" is "Monty", the original creator of MySQL. He set up a new company a few years ago in Sweden after the MySQL code copyright had fallen into the hands of Oracle. He is a nice chap with a lot to say, but he fails to setup a business case simply _because_ there is no real world difference between MySQL and MariaDB. That documentation you cited does _not_ support your general statement. I cannot see any real difference in the "command line interface" and since both variants use the same base engines there is no difference in how powerfull they are.

Comment: - "Our History
MariaDB was created in 2009 by the same people behind MySQL, one of the most popular Open Source relational databases. The founders were inspired to develop MariaDB as an alternative to MySQL, after Oracle acquired MySQL through the Sun Microsystems acquisition."
- It's not exacly the same engine.
- I can only recommand you to try both to compare them.

Comment: They are identical in >98%. Which is not surprising, since it is a fork. A fork that has received commits only in few areas. Yes, there are two storage engines only available in MariaDB, that is true. But as already said those are not in everyday scenarios.

Comment: The term "by the same people behind MySQL" is political correct talking. Fact is that one person took initiative when Oracle purchased Sun Microsystems: Monty (Michael Widenius). Take a look here to understand the history: https://blog.openshift.com/why-mariadb-matters-the-openshift-interview-with-monty/