# How to create a '.sql' file

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a database using 'CREATE DATABASE Gameshop;' for my class and I need to hand it in as an '.sql' file but, I don't know where to look for the file or how to create it.
I am worried I will lose all of my work if I attempt something and fail. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to export and import an .sql file from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line)

Comment: Is this on your own machine? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4):

In your command prompt (NOT mySQL command line):

Use `$ mysqldump -u <username> -p<passwprd> db_name > db_backup.sql` in order to dump the entire database on to an SQL file from the command line.

To import back use `$ mysql -u <username> -p -h localhost db_name < db_backup.sql`

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) for more details.

Comment: I get this error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump' at line 1" when i try to use mysqldump in the command prompt

Comment: @AnthonyHerrera , Are you sure you are typing this at the command prompt of your OS and not in your MySQL server? Be sure not to use the $.

Comment: You have to use shell command prompt not mysql command prompt

Comment: '$' sign is useless

Comment: It is in the mysqld prompt. how do i get to the shell command prompt without losing my work?

Comment: @AnthonyHerrera Even if you close MySQL your work should still be there. Any SQL commands are saved automatically so will be there even if your system gets shut down. The main exceptions here are if you disabled autocommit or started a transaction that you did not commit.

Answer (score 4):

You could export your database using the export wizard of your Database IDE(MySQL Workbench,phpmyadmin, Sequel Pro etc...) or else if you are using command line for single database use

```
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

for Multiple databases

```
mysqldump --databases database_one database_two > two_databases.sql
```

for all databases on server

```
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Comment: I get this error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump' at line 1" when i try to use mysqldump in the command prompt.

Comment: could you post the sql statement and also are using simple command prompt or mysql command line. you need to use shell command prompt not mysql command prompt

Comment: mysql command line. mysqldump -uch0mpy -p Gameshop > "C:\Users\ch0mpy\Desktop\backup.sql"

Comment: Don't use mysql command line. Use your normal command prompt.

Comment: How do i get to the normal command prompt from mysql without losing all of my work?

Comment: Just open one in another window. mySQL will still be there, don't exit that.