# Getting Database putting into sql file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get my database example_dog_names into a sql file. The command I have tried to do this is:

```
example_dog_names > C:/Users/man/Desktop/dbfile.sql;
```

The error that I am getting says:

```
     ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
     check the manual that corresponds to your 
     MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
     'example_dog_names < C:/Users/man/Desktop/dbfile.sql' at line 1
```

What am I missing? I am connected to MySQL, and I executed the command:

```
USE example_dog_names;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "get my database into a sql file". Do you want to export the database into sql file..or do you want to open a database within sql file?

Comment: I want to export the data into the database file

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-an-sql-file-from-command-line