# Way to migrate windows app in cloud?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-services, migration, cloud

How do organizations plan to deploy/migrate their windows application in cloud?

Assume the database is MySQL and backend in flask, PyQT as the frontend, how would one migrate?

To get an idea of software, think of a payroll app created with Visual Basics....

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: How to export and import a .sql file from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/mysql-how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line)

Comment: There's nothing Windows-specific about MySQL, Flask, or PyQT as far as I know, but if you're trying to migrate apps that only run on Windows (like Visual Basic apps) then you can run Windows on EC2, of course.

Comment: If this is a high-level migration question, perhaps the best place to start is https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-migration/. There are plenty of resources, tools, and guides there for moving applications to AWS.