# Creating Sql File From Sql Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a huge amount of data in **MariaDB**. I need to do create dump files from queries. So far I got something like this.

`SELECT DISTINCT uretici INTO OUTFILE '/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/public/manufacturers.sql'   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   FROM data;`

This gives me a SQL file which is cant be imported. I need an importable SQL file. What to do about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export and import a .sql file from command line with options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407349/how-to-export-and-import-a-sql-file-from-command-line-with-options)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command

```
mysqldump -u [database_user] -p [database_name] | gzip > [filename_to_compress.sql.gz]
```

Comment: If you need any clarifications please let me know

Comment: Thank you for your answer samuel. I solve this problem while ago with the following command.
```
mysqldump -u root -pxxx admin_tecalliance data -w "oem_no IS NOT NULL " > file.sql;"
```