# How to populate database from file when in the MySQL console

Tags: mysql, populate

How can I populate a database from a sql file when I'm in the mysql console?
 `LOAD DATA INFILE` doesn't fit my problem. I want to populate the whole database, not only one table. `mysql -u root -p database < file.sql` won't work either. Because I cannot out of the mysql console.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it from the `mysql` command. Can you use MySQL Workbench? It has import/export.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-from-mysql-console

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen It's a dupplicated. I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You want to bulk insert at commandline? Why not use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

```
shell> mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

Comment: I cannot out of the Mysql console. So I cannot use `mysqlimport`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. You said "when I'm in the mysql console". What do you mean by "i cannot out of the mysql console"?

Comment: Excactly that ;). When I'm `exit` the console closes, I do not return to a shell. It's Windows...