# How can I run a .sql file from the query tab?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench and I have a series of .sql files stored from on my computer. I want to run these files from the query tab, but every time I use this command:

`source '/Users/[username]/Documents/company/department.sql';`

I get an Error 1064, which says `"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> source '/Users/[username]/Documents/company/department.sql' at line 1
"`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you open department.sql from MySQL Workbench instead of sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL console.

```
 mysql> use DB_NAME;
 mysql> source 'Users/[username]/Documents/company/department.sql';
```

Got the above from the answer here.
[Import SQL file into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-from-mysql-console)

Also. From Console.

```
mysql -u root -p DB_NAME < Users/[username]/Documents/company/department.sql
```

I am not that familiar with MySQL WorkBench. I prefer using the console but these are the two methods to do what you want assuming that your .sql file contains proper sql.

Comment: The issue is I'm not in the console I'm in the query tab (unless they're the same thing; I'm a newbie here). Do I type in the "mysql>" part?

Comment: no don't type in "mysql>". have you tried what I said to do above? If you have and it still does not work then are you sure the sql file is properly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

The source command as well as the variant using the left angle char are solely features of the command line client. They make absolutely no sense in a GUI like MySQL Workbench. If you want to run a script open it in the SQL editor and click the button with the flash in the editor's toolbar to run it.

Comment: It makes perfect sense if you want to run a defined series of sql script files.

Comment: I agree. In order to automate script execution and history it would be essential to have this functionality.