# Importing huge sql file using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, large-files

I am trying to import 2 GB `sql` file of table. I tried using bigdump but it failed.  Can any body help me in this regard? I am using `phpmyadmin` by increasing the `max_upload_filesize`. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome at SO. Your question does not contain enough information to analyze the problem. Please include the error message and other relevant information you have.

Comment: @patric hofman : there is not any error. it just takes very long time to do the job done. there is 2 gb sql file for the table and when i import it takes so much time. i have also tried to execute the sql file it also takes very long time. plz suggest me the easy slution to import the sql file in my phpmyadmin in less time. Your any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**How To**

Make sure you change both *"post_max_size"* and *"upload_max_filesize"* in your "php.ini" (which is located where your "php.exe" is).

The following example allows you to upload and import 128MB sql files:

```
post_max_size=128M
upload_max_filesize=128M
```

Restart Apache and you're all set.

**Alternatives**

An alternative way to work around the problem is to use the command line. But it's a workaround, and as ugly as workarounds get:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\mysql.exe -u root -p db_name < C:\some_path\your_sql_file.sql
```

As you're not using the server but the command line, upload and POST sizes don't matter. That's why I call this a "workaround", since it doesn't actually solve your problem.

Comment: i am importing this file on live database of my website. how can i change the suggested changes in php.ini file

Comment: @user3427967 You haven't mentioned that in your question!

Comment: @user3427967 check this out: for WHM/Cpanel (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/increase-upload-database-size-for-cpanel-and-phpmyadmin-server/)

Comment: @arshad yes i am using whl/cpanel. i have checked  out your suggested link but cant find the tweak setting option over there. i have tried to execute the sql dump file that i dumped from localhost i.e wampp but it takes too much time.

Comment: @user3427967 Ok, check is it successful in wamp after making suggested changes. If gives error then mention that error in your question/comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the mysql console like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-from-mysql-console) and it worked for me! (It will take a while)