# Can I export a Sqlite db using RedBean PHP ORM and Import to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, redbean

I have a simple web app that I've been building using `redbean` PHP which has a really simple structure with three bean types:

areas
buildings
persons

All relationships are exclusive 1:Many. So, a `Person` belongs to only 1 `Building`, and a `Building` belongs to 1 `Area`.

```
Area
  BuildingList
    PersonList
```

Currently, I have been developing it using `Sqlite3` for ease of development, but I want to move the data to `mySQL`. I have a lot of data that I've already added.

Is there an easy way to use RedBean to Export ALL beans to the new MySql Database?

I know I can search for a `sqlite` -> `MySQL`/`MariaDB` converter, but I also potentially want to be able to use this in reverse to make migrating the site super easy to move/backup/change DBs.

What I've tried below:

```
R::setup('sqlite:/' . __DIR__ . '/data/database.db'); 
R::addDatabase('mysql', $MySqlConn );

$old_datas = R::findAll( 'area' );
R::selectDatabase( 'mysql' );

foreach ($old_datas as $bean) {
    $new_area = R::dispense('area');
    $new_area->importFrom( $bean );
    $id = R::store( $new_area );
    var_dump( $new_area ); // shows new data
}

var_dump( R::findAll( 'area' ) ); // returns empty array
```

Comment: Have you tried `exportAll()` mentioned in [redbean docs](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/import_and_export)?

Comment: `exportAll()` is great and all and might work using recursion to add to the MySQL db. I haven't gone too far down that path, but it's looking more and more likely that I'll have to write the functions to do it manually like this.

Comment: Can I suggest [Fregata](https://github.com/AymDev/Fregata) (disclaimer: I am the author) ? There is a [demo project](https://github.com/AymDev/Fregata-demo) with a **MySQL** to **PostgreSQL** example migration if you want. It is ORM/database agnostic, although there's a integrated *Doctrine DBAL* foreign keys migration system but you can ignore it. I never worked with RedBean but I'd be glad to write a detailed answer if you have specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying that I've not personally tried to do so, but since you can dump an entire database via the sqlite3 console, then my first approach would be to do so, and then try importing that file into MySQL.

Dumping a sqlite3 database from the sqlite console:

`sqlite> output database_dump.sql
 sqlite> .dump
 sqlite> .quit`

Importing a .sql file into MySQL (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-into-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top)):

`mysql> use DATABASE_NAME
 mysql> source path/to/file.sql`