# Which one is faster to import 50GB data into MySQL? In-database source or shell command read file?

Tags: mysql, import, database-backups

I used this command `mysqldump -u root -p etl_db > ~/backup.sql` to get the backup data.

Now I want to import into a new remote MySQL database.
I saw there are 2 ways to do it.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

I wonder which one would be faster?

`shell> mysql < dump.sql`
or
`mysql> source dump.sql`?

I saw some people says that `source` is for small data but there are others say that [it's good for large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-into-mysql?rq=1). I couldn't find much documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason for it to be any different in speed reading the dump, and the database inserts will be the limiting factor, not the speed of reading the dump.

Comment: @user207421is there any way to improve the speed to insert?