# How to extract data from 200mb+ .sql dump file

Tags: mysql

Context, I am trying to explore the sales data of my friend's small restaurant. The system is set up to make copies of the database only locally, that is, not into the cloud. I rooted around the computer and found the backup files of the database, in .sql format. Filesize is approximately 200mb.

Quick googling tells me that a .sql file is a sql script. I opened the file in MySQL Workbench. Screenshot linked below. Workbench keeps on crashing, I suppose the file is too big?

Question #1: aren't data and code supposed to be stored in separate files?

Question #2: How to extract the data (e.g. into a csv file) from the file?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TrV3.jpg

Comment: no they aren't separated in a sql file, and run the script and extract the data from the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import SQL file into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152921/import-sql-file-into-mysql)